# Profile not activating with multiple conditions and jdk

Tags: java, maven, build, pom.xml

if we want to activate a profile 'java8' based on if installed jdk is 1.8. and only if other profile 'dev' is also active. so to achieve that i have setted a property isDev and checking this property in java8 activation condition.

```
<profiles>
 <profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <properties>
        <isDev>true</isDev>
    </properties>
    ...
  </profile>

  <profile>
    <id>java8</id>
    <activation>
      <jdk>1.8</jdk>
      <property>
        <name>isDev</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

when i list all activated profile with command `mvn -Pdev help:active-profiles` only dev is active
*output:*

```
The following profiles are active:

 - dev (source: com.myproject:tts:3.2.0)
```

maven.version 3.8.1

Comment: To activate profiles you cannot use properties defined in the POM. This includes properties from other profiles.

Comment: @JFabianMeier where is it mentioned? Can u give me reference doc.